# MIPS Bubble sorting variably assigned array

Tags: arrays, mips, bubble-sort

So ive been able to create an array that is the size of what the user chooses and the code proceeds to Sort just fine when debugging, the issue is for some reason its not getting past Sort and into swap and im not quite sure why. In the debugger it seems to read the code to swap but then skips over it and repeats sort in an infinite loop. Am i doing something wrong?

```
.data
count: .word 0
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the array size \n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter integers to fill the array \n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Sorted Array: "

.text

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

sw $v0, count

sll $a0, $v0, 2
li $v0, 9
syscall
move $t0, $v0
lw $t1, count

loop:


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall


li $v0, 5
syscall

beqz $v0, sort
sw $v0, 0($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 4

sub $t1, $t1, 1
bnez $t1, loop

sort:
lw $t3, 0($t0)
lw $t4, 4($t0)
blt $t4, $t3, swap
addiu $t0, $t0, 4
addi $t1, $t1, -1
bne $t1, $zero, sort
jr $ra

swap:
sw $t3, 4($t0)
sw $t4, 0($t0)
j sort

end:

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: In `loop` you modify the base address (`$t0`) and loop counter (`$t1`) that will be used by `sort`. Also, why is there a `jr $ra` after the sort loop? You didn't `jal` to `sort`.

Comment: the JAL was left over and code i forgot to delete. so the issue is that im modifying and essentially overwriting the base address and loop counter that is used in sort and thats why none of the values seem like theyre being saved or able to be accessed? Would i fix this by setting another register equal to 0(t0) and so on?